# Why is Bing Custom Search API throwing an error when I make a call through node-js?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I was using Bing Custom Search API for the past week with no problems thanks to the free trial, but today, I tried upgrading to the S1 plan, since the API was sending error messages. I tried regenerating the key as well, but despite doing both of these things, I was still getting errors and unable to use the API.

However, I was able to make calls using: https://www.customsearch.ai/applications, where I was able to use my API key to test endpoints and get the results I expected. What baffles me is that my nodejs code which hasn't been modified aside from the subscription key should still work with the upgraded plan, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should be able to help here. Let us do little bit of troubleshooting once:

1. First go to https://www.customsearch.ai/applications -> click on your instance name ->Click on "Production" tab on top -> Try making API call on this page by providing Query and Subscription key you got. If this works, go to the next step.
2. On the page mentioned above you would have seen Custom Configuration ID and Subscription Key. Make sure those two are same in your node.js code. Ideally this should work.
3. If it still doesn't work, please share your error code so that I can get better understanding of the error you are getting.